# How to know if an notification has been cancelled?

Tags: android, notifications

My little app sends some notifications. We get a callback via a Pendingintent when the notification is clicked on. However, when a notification is simply removed without being clicked on, I don't get any kind of notification and thus wouldn't know if a notification has been removed by the user.

My ultimate goal is to limit the number of active notifications sent by my app to no more than 3. But I haven't been able to find a way to enumerate or simply get the count of active notifications sent by my app. The number of methods available in NotificationManager is rather limited.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `PendingIntent` with [setDeleteIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setDeleteIntent(android.app.PendingIntent)) which will be called when the notification is removed from the notification tray (such as when the user swipes to dismiss it).

Do note that the [notification design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html#summarize_your_notifications) state:

> If a notification of a certain type is already pending when your app tries to send a new notification of the same type, combine them into a single summary notification for the app. Do not create a new object.
>
> A summary notification builds a summary description and allows the user to understand how many notifications of a particular kind are pending.

I.e., don't do this:
[image: Don't do this]

Do this (this example uses an [InboxStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.InboxStyle.html) notification as is recommended):
[image: Do this: stack notifications]

Make sure you are not posting multiple notifications of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

the method  "Notification.deleteIntent" you can use to set a PendingIntent which the notification was removed by system will be called .And then you can do something you want .

Comment: Could you be moe elaborate?